# Fade Out/In Divs On Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, effect

Please I Want To Hover On specific Div And when i so it , just the specific hide the shown side and the other show , but the problem is that all the divs hidden and shown in same time .

```
$(".service").on('mouseover', function () {  
    $(".face1").fadeOut();
    $(".face2").fadeIn();
});
$(".service").on('mouseout', function () {
    $(".face2").fadeOut();
    $(".face1").fadeIn();
});
```

Here Is The Demo : https://codepen.io/abcari/pen/JMjjow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most use `$(this)` to prevent all element with same class name `.face1` and `.face2` to act same and also prevent from affection by same event.

**Jquery**:

```
$(".service").on('mouseenter', function () {

    $(this).find(".face1").fadeOut();
    $(this).find(".face2").fadeIn();

});

$(".service").on('mouseleave', function () {

    $(this).find(".face2").fadeOut();
    $(this).find(".face1").fadeIn();

});
```

[**Article about $(this)**](http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/)

An update based on OP ask:

**CSS**:

```
.service .face2 {position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;display:none;transform:translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);text-align:center;}
```

Add this in very last line in your css file.
[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s9hf9rku/) (is just for transition purpose)

Comment: thanks bro it worked but please if u dont mind , the time when it works , it don't fadeIn normally , please have a look on the codepen link and try to see what i'm trying to explain to you Please Friend .

Comment: @Patrek Ok, please set this answer as an answer for another viewer to find it useful.

Comment: @Patrek That's the CSS issue. You want to have smooth fade in/out, right?

Comment: yeah bro , if you can help me Out

Comment: @Patrek Check new update. You most add new line in your css and also check the jsfiddle in post.